# Saponification side reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, hydrolysis, saponification

When soap is made from triglycerides and NaOH reacting, is saponification the only reaction that occurs or are there other side reactions. Information concerning this issue seems slim online

Comment: Hmm, have you any ideas? I can think of few, but I'm not sure about their viability - esters can react using their alpha carbons, maybe even diallylic carbons.

Comment: This may assist you - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claisen_condensation